# Closed form of $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\tanh(x)\,\tanh(2x)}{x^2}\;dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I have homework to evaluate this integral
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\tanh(x)\,\tanh(2x)}{x^2}\;dx$$

---

Here is what I have done so far. I tried integration by parts using $u=\tanh(x)\,\tanh(2x)$ and $dv=\frac{dx}{x^2}$, I got
$$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\tanh(x)\,\tanh(2x)}{x^2}\;dx&=-\left.\frac{\tanh(x)\,\tanh(2x)}{x}\right|_{0}^{\infty}+2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\tanh(2x)\,\text{sech}(2x)}{x}\;dx\\&=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\tanh(2x)\,\text{sech}(2x)}{x}\;dx\end{align}$$
At this part I'm stuck. I'm thinking of using Frullani's integral but I'm having trouble to find a relation as such $\tanh(2x)\,\text{sech}(2x)=f(ax)-f(bx)$.

I also tried using differentiation under integral sign by considering
$$I(a,b)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\tanh(ax)\,\tanh(bx)}{x^2}\;dx$$
then
$$\frac{dI}{da}=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\text{sech}^2(ax)\,\tanh(bx)}{x}\;dx=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\tanh(bx)-\tanh^2(ax)\tanh(bx)}{x}\;dx$$
Again I tried to use Frullani's integral but I'm having trouble to find the sufficient $f(x)$. Integrating again with respect to $b$, I got
$$\frac{d^2I}{da\;db}=\int_{0}^{\infty} \text{sech}^2(ax)\text{sech}^2(bx)\;dx$$
It's obviously a dead end to me. At this rate my friends and I contacted my professor to confirm whether the integral can be evaluated in terms of elementary functions or not because W|A cannot find it (I know that W|A cannot do everything). He only said, "*Sure! The answer is only 3 characters*" and then he left us. Assuming he is right, so $I$ must have a nice closed form, but I'm unable to find it.

Would you help me? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: just as comment: The substitution $x=arctanh(y)$ together with $\tanh(2x)=\frac{2 \tanh(x)}{1+\tanh(x)^2}$ is maybe worth to give it a try.

Comment: @tired I did, but it got complicated

Comment: at which point?

Comment: @tired At the denominator: $\text{arctanh}\,(y)^2$

Comment: i tried a litte bit, and indeed things didn't get really easier...:-(

Comment: This is a beautiful integral, did you really get this as homework?

Comment: @user111187 Yes. This is an extra problem from our prof so that we can get extra marks for calculus course

Comment: @Alizter No, like I said. This is extra problem to get extra marks in Calculus topic

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your professor is right. Note that
$$ \tanh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}, \tanh(2x)=\frac{e^{2x}-e^{-2x}}{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}}=\frac{(e^x-e^{-x})(e^x+e^{-x})}{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}}$$
and hence
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\tanh(x)\tanh(2x)}{x^2}dx&=&\int_0^\infty\frac{(e^{x}-e^{-x})^2}{x^2(e^{2x}+e^{-2x})}dx\\
&=&\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{2x}-2+e^{-2x}}{x^2(e^{2x}+e^{-2x})}dx.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now define
$$ I(a)=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{ax}-2+e^{-ax}}{x^2(e^{2x}+e^{-2x})}dx$$
to get
\begin{eqnarray}
I''(a)&=&\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{(-a-2)x}+e^{(-a+2)x}}{1+e^{-4x}}dx,\\
&=&\int_0^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(e^{(-a-2)x}+e^{(-a+2)x})e^{-4nx}dx\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{4n-a+2}+\frac{1}{4n+a+2}\right)\\
&=&\frac{\pi}{4}\sec\left(\frac{a\pi}{4}\right).
\end{eqnarray}
So
\begin{eqnarray}
I'(a)&=&\int_0^a\frac{\pi}{4}\sec\left(\frac{\pi t}{4}\right)dt\\
&=&\ln\left(1+\sin\left(\frac{\pi a}{4}\right)\right)-\ln\cos\left(\frac{\pi a}{4}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
\begin{eqnarray}
I(2)&=&\int_0^2\ln\left(1+\sin\left(\frac{\pi a}{4}\right)\right)da-\int_0^2\ln\cos\left(\frac{\pi a}{4}\right)da.
\end{eqnarray}
Note
$$ \int_0^2\ln\cos\left(\frac{\pi a}{4}\right)da=-2\ln2 $$
from [Evaluating $\int_0^{\large\frac{\pi}{4}} \log\left( \cos x\right) \, \mathrm{d}x $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199094/evaluating-int-0-large-frac-pi4-log-left-cos-x-right-mathrmdx?lq=1)
and it should not be hard to get
$$ \int_0^2\ln\left(1+\sin\left(\frac{\pi a}{4}\right)\right)da=\frac{8G}{\pi}-2\ln 2$$
and thus
$$ I(2)=\frac{8G}{\pi}. $$

$\bf{Update}$ 1: Let us first work on 
$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{4n-a+2}+\frac{1}{4n+a+2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}\sec\left(\frac{a\pi}{4}\right)$.
In fact
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{4n-a+2}+\frac{1}{4n+a+2}\right)\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{8n-a+2}-\frac{1}{8n-a+6}\right)+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{8n+a+2}-\frac{1}{8n+a+6}\right)\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{4}{(8n-a+2)(8n-a+6)}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{4}{(8n+a+2)(8n+a+6)}\\
&=&\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{4}{(8n-a+2)(8n-a+6)}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{4}{(8n-a+4)^2-2^2}\\
&=&\frac{1}{16}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+\frac{4-a}{8})^2-(\frac{1}{4})^2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now using a result from [Closed form for $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(z+n)^2+a^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608059/closed-form-for-sum-n-infty-infty-frac1zn2a2?rq=1) for $a=\frac{i}{4}$ and $z=\frac{4-a}{8}$ and after some basic calculation we can get this result. Also see [An alternative proof for sum of alternating series evaluates to $\frac{\pi}{4}\sec\left(\frac{a\pi}{4}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019850/an-alternative-proof-for-sum-of-alternating-series-evaluates-to-frac-pi4-s) for a short proof.

$\bf{Update}$ 2: We work on $\int_0^2\ln\left(1+\sin\left(\frac{\pi a}{4}\right)\right)da=\frac{8G}{\pi}-2\ln 2$. In fact
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^2\ln\left(1+\sin\left(\frac{\pi a}{4}\right)\right)da=\frac{4}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\left(1+\sin(a)\right)da=\frac{4}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(1+\cos(a))da.
\end{eqnarray}
Using $2\cos^2\frac{a}{2}=1+\cos a$ and a result $G=\int_0^{\pi/4}\ln(\cos(t))dt$ from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant, it is easy to obtain
$$ \int_0^2\ln\left(1+\sin\left(\frac{\pi a}{4}\right)\right)da=
\frac{8G}{\pi}-2\ln 2. $$

Comment: Amazing! This very simple! You've posted since 19 hrs ago but why I didn't notice it earlier? +1

Comment: Anyway, could you elaborate this part $$\int_0^2\ln\left(1+\sin\left(\frac{\pi a}{4}\right)\right)da=\frac{8G}{\pi}-2\ln 2$$Thanks...

Comment: Never mind, I can handle it. Thanks for your simple & nice solution. :-)

Comment: Sorry, last question. How I can proof this series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{4n-a+2}+\frac{1}{4n+a+2}\right)=\frac{ \pi }{4}\sec\left(\frac{a \pi }{4}\right)$$
Do you have any references? Or did you use residue method? Can you elaborate using real analysis method? Thanks...

Comment: @venus, I added the proof of the series. I will come back to give the proof the integral. It is not trivial.

Comment: @Venus: Let $u=\dfrac\pi4 a$ and $\sin u=\cos\bigg(\dfrac\pi2-u\bigg)$ and $\dfrac{1+\cos t}2=\cos^2\dfrac t2$

Answer (score 20):

Here is a method that avoids complex analysis. That being said however, I think achille hui's approach is far superior as this answer uses too much (unnecessarily) heavy machinery.

Let $x\mapsto-\ln{x}$. We get
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
=\int^1_0\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\frac{1-x^4}{1+x^4}\frac{{\rm d}x}{x\ln^2{x}}
=\int^1_0\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{2x}{1+x^4}\right)\frac{{\rm d}x}{\ln^2{x}}
\end{align}
Define
$$\mathcal{I}(\alpha)=\int^1_0\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{2x}{1+x^4}\right)\frac{x^{\alpha}{\rm d}x}{\ln^2{x}}$$
Differentiating twice, one obtains
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}''(\alpha)
=&\frac{1}{\alpha}-2\sum^\infty_{n=0}(-1)^n\int^1_0x^{4n+\alpha+1}{\rm d}x\\
=&\frac{1}{\alpha}-2\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^n}{4n+\alpha+2}\\
=&\frac{1}{\alpha}-\frac{1}{4}\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{n+\frac{\alpha+2}{8}}+\frac{1}{4}\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{n+\frac{\alpha+6}{8}}\\
=&\frac{1}{\alpha}+\frac{1}{4}\psi_0\left(\frac{\alpha+2}{8}\right)-\frac{1}{4}\psi_0\left(\frac{\alpha+6}{8}\right)
\end{align}
Integrate back once.
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}'(\alpha)
=&\ln{\alpha}+2\ln{\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha+2}{8}\right)}-2\ln{\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha+6}{8}\right)}+C_1
\end{align}
The constant of integration is, by Striling's asymptotic series, $-3\ln{2}$. Now, recall the fact that
$$\int\ln{\Gamma(x)}\ {\rm d}x=\frac{x(1-x)}{2}+\frac{x}{2}\ln(2\pi)+x\ln{\Gamma(x)}-\ln{G(x+1)}+C_2$$
You may find a [proof in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/982048/log-gamma-integral/1010531#1010531). Hence, integrating once again, we obtain
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}(\alpha)
=&\alpha\ln{\alpha}-\alpha-\frac{(\alpha+2)(\alpha-6)}{8}+(\alpha+2)\ln(2\pi)+2(\alpha+2)\ln{\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha+2}{8}\right)}\\
&-16\ln{G\left(\frac{\alpha+10}{8}\right)}+\frac{(\alpha-2)(\alpha+6)}{8}-(\alpha+6)\ln(2\pi)\\
&-2(\alpha+6)\ln{\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha+6}{8}\right)}+16\ln{G\left(\frac{\alpha+14}{8}\right)}-3\alpha\ln{2}+C_2\\
=&C_2-4\ln(2\pi)-3\alpha\ln{2}+\alpha\ln{\alpha}+2(\alpha+2)\ln{\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha+2}{8}\right)}\\
&-2(\alpha+6)\ln{\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha+6}{8}\right)}-16\ln{G\left(\frac{\alpha+10}{8}\right)}+16\ln{G\left(\frac{\alpha+14}{8}\right)}
\end{align}
One may use the asymptotic series of the Barnes G (derived from the log-gamma integral and Stirling's) to check that $C_2=4\ln(2\pi)$. Letting $\alpha\to 0$,
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
=&\mathcal{I}(0)\\
=&4\ln{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}-12\ln{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}-16\ln{G\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)}+16\ln{G\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)}
\end{align}
It remains to simplify this result. Using the Gamma reflection formula $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\pi\csc(\pi z)$, as well as the Barnes G functional equation $G(z+1)=G(z)\Gamma(z)$, we get
$$\mathcal{I}=-6\ln{2}-12\ln{\pi}-16\ln\left(\frac{G\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{G\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)}\right)$$
Now recall that $G(z+1)$ has the infinite product representation
$$G(z+1)=\left(\sqrt{2\pi}\right)^{z}e^{-\frac{(1+\gamma)z^2+z}{2}}\prod^\infty_{k=1}e^{\frac{z^2}{2k}-z}\left(1+\frac{z}{k}\right)^k$$
Taking the logarithm,
\begin{align}
\ln{G(z+1)}
=&-\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z}{2}\ln(2\pi)-\frac{z^2}{2}-\frac{\gamma z^2}{2}+\sum^\infty_{k=1}\left\{k\ln\left(1+\frac{z}{k}\right)+\frac{z^2}{2k}-z\right\}\\
=&-\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z}{2}\ln(2\pi)-\frac{z^2}{2}-\frac{\gamma z^2}{2}+\sum^\infty_{k=1}\left\{\frac{z^2}{2k}-z+\sum^\infty_{m=1}\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{m}\frac{z^m}{k^{m-1}}\right\}\\
=&-\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z}{2}\ln(2\pi)-\frac{z^2}{2}-\frac{\gamma z^2}{2}+\sum^\infty_{k=1}\sum^\infty_{m=3}\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{m}\frac{z^m}{k^{m-1}}\\
=&-\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z}{2}\ln(2\pi)-\frac{z^2}{2}-\frac{\gamma z^2}{2}+\sum^\infty_{m=3}\frac{(-1)^{m-1}\zeta(m-1)}{m}z^m\\
=&-\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z}{2}\ln(2\pi)-\frac{z^2}{2}-\frac{\gamma z^2}{2}+\sum^\infty_{m=2}\frac{(-1)^{m}\zeta(m)}{m+1}z^{m+1}\\
\end{align}
Letting $z\mapsto -z$,
$$\ln{G(1-z)}=\frac{z}{2}-\frac{z}{2}\ln(2\pi)-\frac{z^2}{2}-\frac{\gamma z^2}{2}-\sum^\infty_{m=2}\frac{\zeta(m)}{m+1}z^{m+1}$$
It follows that
\begin{align}
\ln{\frac{G(1-z)}{G(1+z)}}
=&z-z\ln(2\pi)-2\sum^\infty_{m=1}\frac{\zeta(2m)}{2m+1}z^{2m+1}\\
=&-z\ln(2\pi)+\int^z_0\pi x\cot(\pi x)\ {\rm d}x
\end{align}
Let $z=\frac{3}{4}$.
\begin{align}
\ln\left(\frac{G\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{G\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)}\right)
=&-\frac{3}{4}\ln(2\pi)+2\sum^\infty_{n=1}\int^\frac{3}{4}_0\pi x\sin(2n\pi x)\ {\rm d}x\\
=&-\frac{3}{4}\ln(2\pi)+\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\sin(3n\pi/2)}{n^2}-\frac{3}{4}\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\cos(3n\pi/2)}{n}\\
=&-\frac{3}{4}\ln(2\pi)-\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}+\frac{3}{8}\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\\
=&-\frac{3}{8}\ln{2}-\frac{3}{4}\ln{\pi}-\frac{\mathbf{G}}{2\pi}
\end{align}
Finally,
$$\mathcal{I}=-6\ln{2}-12\ln{\pi}-16\left(-\frac{3}{8}\ln{2}-\frac{3}{4}\ln{\pi}-\frac{\mathbf{G}}{2\pi}\right)=\Large{\frac{8\mathbf{G}}{\pi}}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the real method approach. It's ok if it's too complicated, I haven't learned contour integration yet. +1

Comment: @Venus  I am glad you found this answer useful in some way. Thanks.

Comment: +1 because you takes care of writing the result at the very end. Usually we have to guess what was the result. Good.

Answer (score 18):

Let $f(x) = \tanh(x)\tanh(2x)$. Rewrite the integral at hand as
$$I 
= \int_0^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x^2}dx
= \frac12 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^2} dx
= \frac12 \lim_{k\to\infty}
\int_{-k\pi}^{k\pi} \frac{f(x)}{x^2} dx\\
$$
For each positive integer $k$, consider the rectangular region
$$D_k = \big\{ u + iv \in \mathbb{C} : |u| \le k\pi, 0 \le v \le k\pi \big\}$$
and the contour integral over its boundary:

$$C_k \stackrel{def}{=} \int_{\partial D_k} \frac{f(z)}{z^2} dz
= \left(
\int_{-k\pi}^{k\pi}
+ \int_{k\pi}^{k\pi(1+i)} 
+ \int_{k\pi(1+i)}^{k\pi(-1+i)}
+ \int_{k\pi(-1+i)}^{-k\pi} 
\right) \frac{f(z)}{z^2} dz
$$

$C_k$ split into 4 pieces, one for each edges of the $D_k$. It is not hard to show 
as $k \to \infty$, the contribution from the three edges (the top, left and bottom) goes to zero. This implies

$$I = \frac12 \lim_{k\to\infty} \int_{\partial D_k} \frac{f(z)}{z^2} dz\tag{*1}$$

Let $\phi = e^{2z}$, we have

$$\begin{align}f(z) 
&= \tanh(z) \tanh(2z) = \left(\frac{\phi - 1}{\phi+1}\right)\left(\frac{\phi^2-1}{\phi^2+1}\right) = \frac{(\phi-1)^2}{\phi^2+1} = 1 - \frac{2\phi}{\phi^2+1} \\
&= 1 - \frac{1}{\cosh 2z}\end{align}$$

Recall the well known? expansion of $\cot z$

$$\cot z = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{z - n\pi}$$

We have

$$\begin{array}{rrl}
& \frac{1}{\sin z} 
&= \frac{1+\cos z}{\sin z} - \frac{\cos z}{\sin z} = \cot\frac{z}{2} - \cot z = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{z - n\pi}\\
\implies 
& \frac{1}{\cos z} 
&= -\frac{1}{\sin(z - \frac{\pi}{2})} 
= \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{z - (n+\frac12)\pi}\\
\implies
& \frac{1}{\cosh z} 
&= \frac{1}{\cos(-i z)} = 
-i \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{z - (n+\frac12)\pi i}\\
\implies 
& f(z) 
& = 1 + \frac{i}{2} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{z - (n+\frac12)\frac{\pi}{2} i}\tag{*2}
\end{array}$$

Inside $D_k$, $f(z)$ has poles at $(n + \frac12)\frac{\pi}{2} i$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. We can evaluate the contour integral in $(*1)$ by summing the residues at these poles. As a result,

$$I = \frac12 (2\pi i)(\frac{i}{2})\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{((n+\frac12)\frac{\pi}{2}i)^2} = \frac{8K}{\pi}$$

where $\;\displaystyle K = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}\;$ 
is the [Catalan's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant).

**Update**

If one want to minimize the use of complex analysis, an alternate starting point is
the expansion of $f(z)$ in $(*2)$. Let $\alpha_n = (n+\frac12)\frac{\pi}{2}$ and notice
$\alpha_{-1-n} = -\alpha_n$, we have

$$f(x) 
= 1 + \frac{i}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{x -\alpha_n i} - \frac{1}{x + \alpha_n i}\right)
= 1 - \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \alpha_n}{x^2 + \alpha_n^2}
$$
Since $f(0) = 0$, we have

$$\frac{f(x)}{x^2} 
= \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x^2}
= \frac{1}{x^2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \alpha_n\left( \frac{1}{\alpha_n^2} - \frac{1}{x^2 + \alpha_n^2}\right)
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\alpha_n(x^2+\alpha_n^2)}
$$
If you look at the terms of this series in units of pair, we find the value of any pair
is always non-negative. This means we can integrate this series pair by pair and get:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x^2}dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\alpha_n}\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2+\alpha_n^2}
= \frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\alpha_n^2}
= \frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}
= \frac{8K}{\pi}
$$
The same result we obtained using contour integrals.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I hope someone here will give me an answer with a real analysis method. +1. :-)

Comment: Nice answer. +1

Comment: There is a typo in the first line: The second integral 'start' at $-\infty$. Otherwise, it is quite fine => +1.

Comment: Could [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002223) problem be tackled by similar means ?

Comment: @FelixMarin thanks, I fixed that.

Comment: @Lucian, I don't think so. As you say, the $\frac{\pi}{2}$ is not something special for $\tanh z$, I can't think of a suitable curve o "close" the contour.

Answer (score 5):

By symmetry, we have
$$\newcommand{\Res}{\operatorname*{Res}}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\tanh(x)\tanh(2x)}{x^2}\,\mathrm{dx}
=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\tanh(x)\tanh(2x)}{x^2}\,\mathrm{dx}\tag1
$$
There are singularities at $z_k=i\pi\frac{2k+1}4$ and
$$
\Res_{z=z_k}\left(\frac{\tanh(z)\tanh(2z)}{z^2}\right)=(-1)^{k+1}\frac{8i}{\pi^2(2k+1)^2}\tag2
$$
Sum over the telescoping paths
$$
\gamma_k=\color{#090}{\overbrace{\left(-R+i\pi\tfrac k2,R+i\pi\tfrac k2\right)}^\text{these contours telescope}}\cup\color{#C00}{\overbrace{\left(R+i\pi\tfrac k2,R+i\pi\tfrac{k+1}2\right)}^\text{these integrals vanish}}\cup\\
\phantom{\gamma_k}\color{#090}{\left(R+i\pi\tfrac{k+1}2,-R+i\pi\tfrac{k+1}2\right)}\cup\color{#C00}{\left(-R+i\pi\tfrac{k+1}2,-R+i\pi\tfrac k2\right)}\tag3
$$
where $\gamma_k$ contains $z_k$.

[image]

The sum of the residues in the upper half plane times $\pi i$ will be the integral on the half line:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\tanh(x)\tanh(2x)}{x^2}\,\mathrm{dx}
&=\pi i\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}\frac{8i}{\pi^2(2k+1)^2}\tag4\\
&=\frac8\pi\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}\tag5\\[3pt]
&=\frac{8G}\pi\tag6
\end{align}
$$
where $G$ is [Catalan's Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant).

Answer (score 3):

Write
$$
I=\frac{1}{2}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{\tanh(x)\tanh(2x)}{x^2}dx=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{f(x)}{\cosh(\pi x)}dx,
$$
where $f(x)=\frac{2(-1+\cosh(\pi x))}{\pi^2 x^2}$.

Lemma.

If the function $f(z)$ is analytic in $Im(z)>0$ and continuous at $Im(z)\geq 0$. It also satisfies
$$
|f(z)|\leq C (1+|z|)^{N} e^{b |Re(z)|}\textrm{, }0\leq b\leq\pi-\epsilon\textrm{, }\epsilon>0
$$
for all $z$ with $Im(z)\geq 0$ (note: here is $b=\pi$, but $N=-2$), then
$$
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{f(t)}{\cosh(\pi t)}e^{ita}dt=2\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}(-1)^k f(i(k+1/2))e^{-a(k+1/2)}\textrm{, }a>0.
$$
Proof. 
The function $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{\cosh(\pi z)}$ is meromorphic in $Im(z)>0$ and has poles at $z_k=i(k+1/2)$ with 
$$
Res(g;i(k+1/2))=f(i(k+1/2))\frac{(-1)^k}{\pi i}
$$ 
a in the real line and meromorphic at $Im(z)>0$. Hence if $m$ is natural number, $R=m$ and $\gamma_R$ is the upper semicircle of diameter $[-R,R]$, then
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_R}g(z)dz=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{\pi i}f(i(k+1/2))
$$
For we have $|\cos(\pi R e^{i \theta})|\geq c e^{\pi |\cos(\theta)|}$ and
$$
\left|\int^{\pi}_{0}\frac{f(Re^{i\theta})}{\cosh(\pi R e^{i\theta})}iRe^{i\theta}\right|\leq C \left|\int^{\pi}_{0}(1+R)^{-2}Re^{(b-\pi)R|\cos(\theta)|}d\theta\right|\leq C
$$
$$
\leq C \int^{\pi}_{0}(1+R)^{-1}d\theta\rightarrow 0\textrm{, when }R\rightarrow \infty.
$$
$$
QED
$$

For the case
$$
f(x)=\frac{2(-1+\cosh(\pi x))}{\pi^2 x^2}
$$
we have 
$$
I=\frac{\pi}{2}2\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}(-1)^k\frac{8(1+\sin(k\pi))}{\pi^2(2k+1)^2}=\frac{8C}{\pi}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Note

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\tanh x \tanh 2x}{2x^2} dx \overset{t=e^{-2x}} = \int_0^\infty \frac{(1-t)^2dt}{t(1+t^2)\ln^2 t}
\overset{IBP} =\int_0^\infty \frac{2(t^2-1)dt}{(1+t^2)^2\ln t}\\
$$

Let $J(a)=\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{a+1}}{(1+t^2)^2\ln t}dt$
$$J’(a) = \int_0^\infty \frac{t^{a+1}dt}{(1+t^2)^2}
\overset{IBP}
=-\frac a2 \int_0^\infty \frac{t^{a+1}dt}{1+t^2}
=\frac{\pi a}{4}\csc\frac{\pi a}2 $$
Then

$$I= 2\int_{-1}^{1}J’(a)da
\overset{u=\frac{\pi a}2}=\frac4\pi \int_0^{\pi/2}u\csc u\>du
\overset{t=\tan\frac u2} =\frac 8\pi \int_0^{1}\frac {\tan^{-1}t}{t}dt
=\frac{8}{\pi}G
\\
$$

Comment: Very simple solution (+1).

Answer (score 2):

$$
I=\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{\tanh(2x)\tanh(x)}{x^2}dx=\int^{\infty}_{0}\left(1-\frac{1}{\cosh(2x)}\right)\frac{dx}{x^2}=2\int^{\infty}_{0}\left(1-\frac{1}{\cosh(x)}\right)\frac{dx}{x^2}.
$$
Set $x=\cosh^{(-1)}(t)$ to get
$$
I=2\int^{\infty}_{1}\frac{1-1/t}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}\frac{dt}{\cosh^{(-1)}(t)^2}.
$$
From $\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{1}{\cosh^{(-1)}(t)}\right)=\frac{1}{\cosh^{(-1)}(t)^2\sqrt{t^2-1}}$, we get
$$
I=2\int^{\infty}_{1}\frac{1}{t^2\cosh^{(-1)}(t)}dt.
$$ 
Going backwords we set $t=\cosh(y)$. Hence
$$
I=2\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{\tanh(y)}{y\cosh(y)}dy=\frac{8C}{\pi}\tag 1
$$

[(1) is here (relation 41)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalansConstant.html)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a fairly short [residue answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3811212) to this question, but here is a completely real answer.

---

**A Useful Euler Sum**

Applying $(1)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/904248) to $-x^2$ gives
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^kH_kx^{2k}=-\frac{\log\left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x^2}\tag1
$$
and therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}H_k
&=-\int_0^1\frac{\log\left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag2\\
&=2\int_0^{\pi/4}\log(\cos(u))\,\mathrm{d}u\tag3\\
&=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}k\int_0^{\pi/4}\cos(2kx)\,\mathrm{d}x-\frac\pi2\log(2)\tag4\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^2}\sin\left(\frac\pi2k\right)-\frac\pi2\log(2)\tag5\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}-\frac\pi2\log(2)\tag6\\[3pt]
&=\mathrm{G}-\frac\pi2\log(2)\tag7
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(2)$: integrate $(1)$
$(3)$: substitute $x\mapsto\tan(u)$
$(4)$: $\log(\cos(x))=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}k\cos(2kx)-\log(2)$
$\phantom{\text{(13):}}$ as shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1071367)
$(5)$: integrate
$(6)$: $\sin\left(\frac\pi2k\right)=0$ for even $k$
$\phantom{\text{(6):}}$ $\sin\left(\frac\pi2(2k+1)\right)=(-1)^k$
$(7)$: definition of [Catalan's Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant)

---

**The Integral**

Integration by Parts says
$$\newcommand{\sech}{\operatorname{sech}}
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\tanh(x)\tanh(2x)}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=2\int_0^\infty\frac{\sech(2x)\tanh(2x)}x\,\mathrm{d}x\tag8\\
&=2\int_0^\infty\frac{\sech(x)\tanh(x)}x\,\mathrm{d}x\tag9
\end{align}
$$
Using $\pi\cot(\pi x)=\sum\limits_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac1{k+x}$ and $\pi\csc(\pi x)=\sum\limits_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+x}$, as shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3819077), it is not too hard to derive
$$
\frac\pi{4x}\tanh\left(\frac\pi2x\right)
=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac1{(2j+1)^2+x^2}\tag{10}
$$
and
$$
\frac\pi4\sech\left(\frac\pi2x\right)
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k(2k+1)}{(2k+1)^2+x^2}\tag{11}
$$
Furthermore, [Partial Fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) gives
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac1{a^2+x^2}\frac1{b^2+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
=\frac\pi{2(a+b)ab}\tag{12}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
2\int_0^\infty\frac{\tanh(x)\sech(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac8\pi\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+j+1)(2j+1)}\tag{13}\\
&=\frac8\pi\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\left(\frac1{j+\frac12}-\frac1{k+j+1}\right)\frac1{2k+1}\tag{14}\\
&=\frac8\pi\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{\color{#C00}{H_k}\color{#090}{-H_{-1/2}}}{2k+1}\tag{15}\\[3pt]
&=\frac8\pi\left(\color{#C00}{\mathrm{G}-\frac\pi2\log(2)}\color{#090}{+\frac\pi2\log(2)}\right)\tag{16}\\[9pt]
&=\frac{8\mathrm{G}}\pi\tag{17}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(13)$: $(10)$, $(11)$, and $(12)$ with $a=2j+1$ and $b=2k+1$
$(14)$: partial fractions
$(15)$: sum in $j$
$(16)$: apply $(7)$
$\phantom{\text{(16):}}$ the [Gregory Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory%27s_series) says that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}=\frac\pi4$
$\phantom{\text{(16):}}$ [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/506068) computes $H_{-1/2}=-2\log(2)$
$(17)$: cancel $\frac\pi2\log(2)$

Putting together $(9)$ and $(17)$ yields
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\tanh(x)\tanh(2x)}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{8\mathrm{G}}\pi\tag{18}
$$